# Possible bug in Reality Composer Pro GeometryModifier?

Tags: shader-graph, visionos, reality-composer-pro, geometrymodifier

I don't have experience in Computer Graphics, so I am not sure how the `GeometryModifier` of the Reality Composer Pro works. But to me there seems to be a bug (Version 1.0 (385.2)).

To test, I created a scene with a flat box. Its center is placed at the origin, i.e. all its coordinates are on one side negative, on the other side positive.
The model uses a custom surface with a grey color, using a `MaterialXPreviewSurface` node. This node is required to show a preview, in the images below bottom right.

I added a `GeometryModifier` node to manipulate the Model Position Offset. Its input is thus connected to a `Combine3` node that has x, y and z inputs. Without connected inputs, the default value 0 is used.

[image]

To make the cube's geometry dependent on the position of a point within the flat box, a `Position` node is added. Its output vector is decomposed by a `Separate3` node to x, y, and z.

If now the x output is connected to the z input of the `Combine3` node, the flat box is tilt as expected in the preview, and in the main viewport.

[image]

To make the box kinked in the middle, I connected an `Absval` node the the x output, and connected abs(x) to the z input of the `Combine3` node. Now, the preview shows the kinked box, but in the main viewport, the flat box is neither tilt nor kinked, but flat and offset within z.

[image]

This seems to me to be a bug, although I am not sure because of the possibly used different coordinate systems, scaling factors, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Poly Model resolution

This isn't a bug, it's Reality Composer Pro primitives' resolution issue. The cube primitive in RCP has just 8 vertices, or in other words, 6 rect-faces (12 tri-faces). Your cube must have at least two faces along the X axis to apply the GeometryModifier. There are no center edges on your model where the fold line runs.

[image]

So, in a 3D authoring tool (like Maya 2024), create a custom cube primitive with, at least, two divisions on each axis, and then export it as a binary USD file. Now your GeometryModifier for MaterialX will work predictably.

[image]

#### Checking poly-Resolution in visionOS Simulator

In Vision Pro Simulator, you can see RCP cube's 12 triangular faces if you run this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in                
            if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "BoxScene", in: rkcb) {
                let cube = scene.findEntity(named: "Cube") as! ModelEntity
                cube.position = [0.0, 1.0,-2.5]
                
                var mat = UnlitMaterial(color: .yellow)
                mat.triangleFillMode = .lines              // FILL MODE
                cube.model?.materials = [mat]
                content.add(scene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I believe you are right. But I am unable to check it, since my Xcode Version 15.0.1 (15A507) has no longer Reality Composer Pro support ☹️.

Comment: Hi Reinhard, Xcode 15.1 beta 3 (15C5059c) has.

Comment: Great, thanks!!