# Is it possible to load a model with a custom ShaderGraphMaterial in a volumetric window?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I have created my shader graph and attached it to a 3D model in Reality Composer Pro. It loads as expected in a `RealityView` inside an `ImmersiveSpace`.

But when I try to load the same scene in a normal SwiftUI window, the shader graph doesn't appear to work.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct SliceView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't get my shader to work using `Model3D` (for whatever reason), I was able to use a `RealityView` inside of a volumetric window.

For some reason I was under the impression that `RealityView` could only be used in an `ImmersiveSpace`. That is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

In RCP for Xcode 15.3 beta 3, I assigned the `Scratched_Metallic_Paint` material to the USDA sphere (with position `(0.0, 0.5,-1.0) meters`) and as you can see Model3D works fine. After assigning the material, save your RCP scene for the changes to take effect (developers usually forget about this).

```
@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ContentView()
        }
        .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .full)
    }
}
```

It works both in full immersion and in a volumetric window.

```
@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
    }
}
```

Also, if you're using RCP's `GeometryModifier`, make sure you have a [sufficient polygonal resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883339/possible-bug-in-reality-composer-pro-geometrymodifier/77499709#77499709) to displace the desired faces. Thus I do not recommend you using RCP primitives. Use USDA or USDZ models with a sufficient number of polygons. Also, when applying the displacement, use moderate amplitude values.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Model3D(named: "Scene", bundle: realityKitContentBundle) { phase in
            phase.model?.resizable()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that a ShaderGraphMaterial? Mine is using a geometry modifier and the geometry isn’t being modified using Model3D.

Comment: Yes, it's a ShaderGraphMaterial from RCP library.